# $\ker(\phi)$ is a normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be groups and suppose $\phi: G_1\mapsto G_2$ is a homomorphism. Then $\ker (\phi)\unlhd G_1$.

Need some feedback and help proving this. I am still new to proofs, but here's my attempt.

*Proof.*

We want to show $\ker (\phi)$ is normal, therefore, we must show that for any $h\in \ker (\phi)$ and $g\in G_1$, then $ghg^{-1}\in \ker (\phi)$. Since $h\in \ker (\phi)$, then $\phi(h)=1$. Thus,

\begin{align}
\phi(ghg^{-1})&=\phi(g)\phi(h)\phi(g^{-1})\\
&=\phi(g)\cdot 1\cdot\phi(g^{-1})\\
&=\phi(g)\phi(g^{-1})\\
&=\phi(g\cdot g^{-1})\\
&=\phi(1)\\
&=1.
\end{align}

Hence, $ghg^{-1}\in \ker (\phi)$, which implies $\ker (\phi)$ is a normal subgroup in $G_1$.

Comment: This looks good.

Comment: Essentially correct (just have to type the latex nicely). Just need to always remember this whole trick of using the group homomorphism.

Comment: @Everiana: Thanks for your reply. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: must show for **any** $h \in Ker(\phi)...$; also "Therefore, since $h\in Ker(\phi), $ then $\phi(h)=1$" belongs before $\phi(g)\phi(h)\phi(g^{-1})=\phi(g)\cdot1\cdot\phi(g^{-1})$

Comment: Thanks, @J.W.Tanner!

Comment: You can render $\ker \phi$ with the LaTeX `$\ker \phi$`.

Comment: You're welcome.  The way you have it now edited, I would leave out the word "Therefore"; it's true that since $h\in Ker(\phi), \phi(h)=1$, but that doesn't follow from "we must show"

Comment: It would not hurt to emphasize that the last step holds because
$$\phi(g)\phi(g^{-1})=\phi(g)\phi(g)^{-1}=1
\qquad\text{ or }\qquad
\phi(g)\phi(g^{-1})=\phi(gg^{-1})=\phi(1)=1,$$
whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You're right.

An alternative method, following yours right until the end, goes like this:

\begin{align}
\phi(ghg^{-1})&=\phi(g)\phi(h)\phi(g^{-1}) \\
&=\phi(g)\cdot 1\cdot \phi(g^{-1})\\
&=\phi(g)\phi(g)^{-1}\\
&=1.
\end{align}

The conclusion is, of course, the same.